# End-to-end bandwidth allocation to n pairs of nodes

Tags: graphs, network-flow, resource-allocation

Suppose there is a weighted graph representing a network with available bandwidth. I want to allocate end-to-end bandwidth between a set of pairs of nodes to transfer data. I want to find a path and allocate bandwidth to these pairs over that path and cover the most number of pairs possible. To solve this, I used shortest-widest path as a greedy algorithm but certainly, there are cases where this would cause problem and we can support more pairs to communicate with each other. I searched for a while but I could not find the exact problem, any suggestion on how I can solve it?

To elaborate, there is a network like in the following figure and there is bandwidth for each link (which is the maximum capacity of that link).

[image: network]

Connected to these switches are the hosts, as the input of the problem we have host pairs and required bandwidth, for instance, [h1, h2, 20Mbps]. The offline version of the problem has all the input data at the beginning and we want to maximize the number of input accepted by the network, by accepting input entry we find a path between those hosts and allocate the required bandwidth, in addition, the used bandwidth on each link can not be used by any other input entry. Shortest-widest path seems to be a good greedy algorithm for this problem, but in some cases it is not giving the best answer.

Comment: Could you state your problem more formally?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I edited the original questions and added some details.